Clustering based on distance
I have a layer 1060 points and I want to create cluster of point that are within 200 m of each other. I have tried DoCluster tool with no success. I don´t want to pre-define the number of clusters I want to know how many cluster are based and that threshold distance.

Try using the MMQGIS plugin.  It could be a useful alternative for this problem if you don't want to define a minimum number of points to specify a cluster. You should be able to create hub lines and configure the hub lines with your maximum distance requirement. This could be another good way to visualize clusters.
You could also utilize the DBSCAN clustering tool but set the minimum cluster size as 2, so it will contain all possible clusters within 200 m of each other.

I ended up doing it with the GroupPointsWithinDistance plugin it was super easy, highly recommended.
